# Clarrify definite/semi-definite properties

Tags: matrices

I have matrix $P=ABA^*$ where $A$ can be a complex matrix with size $n\times m$.

Does the behavior of $P$ depend on $B$?

For example, if $B$ is positive definite or positive semi-definite, then $P$ is also positive definite or positive semi-definite, respectively?

Please let me know any reference for this property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Let $B=I$. Let $A=A^{\ast}=0$, and let $P=0$ then $B$ is positive definite but $P$ clearly isn't.